# Согласование в названии учреждения

Tags: согласование

Скажите, пожалуйста, какой из представленных вариантов склонения является корректным и почему:

1. Утвердить Правила приема в Федеральное государственное бюджетное учреждение науки Федеральн**ого** исследовательск**ого** центр**а** "Высокотехнологичный научный центр Российской академии наук".
2. Утвердить Правила приема в Федеральное государственное бюджетное учреждение науки Федеральн**ый** исследовательск**ий** центр "Высокотехнологичный научный центр Российской академии наук".

Наши делопроизводственники утверждают, что корректен второй вариант, так как якобы "Федеральное бюджетное государственное учреждение науки" несмотря на присутствие развернутого варианта *подразумевает* сокращение ФГБУН и, исходя из этого, оно *как бы* таким и представляется, поэтому склонение такое: "...Правила приёма в (*ФГБУН*) Федеральн**ый** исследовательск**ий** центр".

Спасибо!

Comment: Без ста грамм не разберёшься...

Comment: В смысле сложно сделать выбор из двух вариантов? :)

Comment: Да нет, просто непонятно, учреждение относится к  Федеральному исследовательскому центру или второй часть его названия. ;) Во втором случае ФИЦ должен тоже закавычиваться, но тогда получается ещё один центр внутри этого...

Comment: Падеж винительный (приём во что?) определяет форму, идентичную официальному названию организации в именительном падеже. Делопроизводители правы.

Answer (score 0):

Может быть, пройдёт такой вариант: *Правила приёма в ФГБУН «Федеральный исследовательский центр»*?